# How do I get the event from onValueMouseOver in react-vis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, react-vis

According to the [react-vis doc](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/general-principles/interaction), `onValueMouseOver` should return both the `event` and the `datapoint`. However, the event does not seem to be passed. Am I doing something wrong?

```
const Charts = () => {
  const data = [
    { x: 1, y: 1 },
    { x: 2, y: 1 },
    { x: 3, y: 5 },
    { x: 4, y: 5 },
    { x: 5, y: 1 },
  ];

  return (
    <XYPlot height={400} width={400}>
      <VerticalBarSeries
        data={data}
        onValueMouseOver={(datapoint, event) => {
          console.log(event.target); // undefined
        }}
      />
    </XYPlot>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the `event` parameter has an `event` property that you can use and access the actual event.

You either do it like this:

```jsx
<VerticalBarSeries
  data={data}
  onValueMouseOver={(datapoint, event) => {
    console.log(event.event.target); // Some SVG element
  }}
/>
```

or using destructuring:

```jsx
<VerticalBarSeries
  data={data}
  onValueMouseOver={(datapoint, { event }) => {
    console.log(event.target); // Some SVG element
  }}
/>
```